# NetConnection.Connect.Rejected error when connectin to red5 server

Tags: flash, apache-flex, streaming, flash-builder

I am new in flex.I have created dynamic web project. Run it. It accessible on http://localhost:5080/myApp. Now I want to create connection to that application but I got NetConnection.Connect.Rejected. This is my code:

```
import mx.core.UIComponent;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        private var connection:NetConnection;
        private var inStream:NetStream;
        private var outStream:NetStream;


        private var camera:Camera;
        private var microphone:Microphone;


        private var inVideo:Video;
        private var outVideo:Video;


        private var inVideoWrapper:UIComponent;
        private var outVideoWrapper:UIComponent;



        protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            connection = new NetConnection();
            connection.connect("rtmp://localhost/myApp");
            connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onConnected);

        }

        private function onConnected(event:NetStatusEvent):void
        {
            if(event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success")
            {
                setupVideo();
            }
        }

        private function setupVideo():void
        {
            camera = Camera.getCamera();
            microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();

            outStream = new NetStream(connection);
            outStream.attachCamera(camera);
            outStream.attachAudio(microphone);
            outStream.publish("Radislav");

            outVideo = new Video();
            outVideo.attachCamera(camera);

            inStream = new NetStream(connection);
            inStream.play("Radislav");

            inVideo = new Video();
            inVideo.attachNetStream(inStream);


            outVideoWrapper = new UIComponent;
            outVideoWrapper.addChild(outVideo);
            addElement(outVideoWrapper);


            inVideoWrapper = new UIComponent;
            inVideoWrapper.addChild(inVideo);
            addElement(inVideoWrapper);

            inVideoWrapper.move(400,0);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short - you need the second parameter in `connection.connect()` call. But you want to read the server logs (red5/jvm) for more details. If you don't see logs, here it explains how to make the server write them: http://avchathq.com/blog/missing-red5-log-files-where-are-they/

Comment: yes, I understand. I found solution yesterday. It wat exactly as you said. Thanks!